# Forma correcta de usar la directiva @include de Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy intentando hacer un layout general y vistas parciales para incluirlas con la directiva include, pero apenas uso la primera @include('includes.sidebar') tengo error 500 en mi pagina (ni idea de a que se debe). Hace un momento funcionó pero me incluía el contenido externo repitiendolo como si estuviera en un bucle. Se repetía una y otra vez pero no tengo ningún bucle. Pareciera ser culpa de la directiva porque cuando la quito todo se ve bien.
Utilice la directiva @yield pero no incluye el contenido, y despues de googlear porque sucedia esto pude ver que aconsejaban mejor el uso de include en este caso ya que tenia problemas con la ruta y la vista renderizada por la funcion del controlador para encontrar el contenido a incluir con yield, asi que decidi usar @include. Dejare fragmentos de código para que me ayuden porfa, Agradecida. :)

```
<div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background: #001b01">

           @include('includes.sidebar')

         </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">


          @yield('content')
          </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: Pero es que `yield` e `include` cumplen funciones distintas, uno es para insertar uan vista completa dentro de otra y por lo que entiendo tu solo tratas de insertar un fragmento de código

Answer (score 1):

La directiva `include` de acuerdo con la documentación permite incluir toda una vista dentro de otra, incluyendo todas las variables declaradas en la vista principal.

**Ejemplo**

Tenemos una vista principal en la siguiente ruta: `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` con el siguiente contenido:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       {{ date('Y') }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Posterior incluyo esta vista en una principal llamada `main.blade.php` lo cual se verá de este modo:

```
@include('welcome')
```

Lo cual va a imprimir en el navegador:

```
2019
```

Pero si revisamos a nivel de código fuente tenemos esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo dado tu escenario me parece que no es lo que debes de hacer si tratas de incluir fragmentos de código en tu vista principal, es decir tienes un html y solo tratas de agregar un `sidebar` dado lo cual creo que tu vista `welcome` debería verse así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Vista principal</h1>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Donde usamos la directiva `yield` para indicar el que se muestre el contenido de una sección.

De modo que la vista hija, herede de la principal con esta sintaxis:

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('content')
    <ul>
        <li>Uno</li>
        <li>Dos</li>
        <li>Tres</li>
        <li>Cuatro</li>
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Dando en el navegador este resultado:

```
Vista principal
Uno
Dos
Tres
Cuatro
```

De modo que si ahora tratas de agregar una nueva sección a tu vista, entonces pudieras hacer esto en la vista principal:

```
@yield('content')
@yield('sidebar') //esta es la nueva sección
```

Y en la vista hija generar el contenido para `sidebar` de esta forma:

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('content')
    <ul>
        <li>Uno</li>
        <li>Dos</li>
        <li>Tres</li>
        <li>Cuatro</li>
    </ul>
@endsection

@section('sidebar')
    <h1>Contenido del sidebar</h1>
@endsection
```

Que nos daría en el navegador algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencias**

- [Herencia de vistas](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#template-inheritance)
- [incluir vistas](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#including-sub-views)